# How to create gantt charts in visual studio C# vsto excel project?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How to create gantt charts in visual studio C# vsto excel project?

My project is excel workbook, and when the user clicks a button
I want a gantt chart to be shown. Excel does not have gantt charts
so I was wondering what options are available?

Comment: may be helpful: [Create a Gantt chart in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-gantt-chart-in-excel-HA001034605.aspx) and [How to Create a Gantt Chart in Excel](http://www.smartsheet.com/blog/gantt-chart-excel#.U2o7us8r_mc)

Comment: But that is not creating gantt charts from code.

Comment: Since there are no native Gantt charts in excel, you will need to either 1) figure out how to code the process shown in @simoco's link 2) create an Excel-embeddable component to display (interactive? editable?) Gantt charts, or 3) render the chart as an image in your C# code and insert it to the worksheet.